# Replace pattern from first column in file2 by pattern in second column in file2 within file1

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have tried to work on a solution for the following: I have a .gff3 file for which I want to replace gene headers into a simplified name. Both the original gene headers and the new gene name are given in a separate file, with the original name in column 1 and the new name in column 2. How can I use sed (I think sed is most suitable here) to replace all occurences in the .gff3 file with the new shortened name in the second column?

Example lines .gff3 file:

```
tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon .   contig  1   93354   .   .   .   ID=tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon;Name=tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon
tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon maker   gene    19497   23038   .   +   .   ID=maker-tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon-augustus-gene-0.4;Name=maker-tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon-augustus-gene-0.4
tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon maker   mRNA    19497   23038   .   +   .   ID=maker-tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon-augustus-gene-0.4-mRNA-1;Parent=maker-tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon-augustus-gene-0.4;Name=maker-tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon-augustus-gene-0.4-mRNA-1;_AED=0.00;_eAED=0.00;_QI=418|1|1|1|0|0|3|2100|206
```

Example lines replacement file:

> ```
> augustus_masked-tulip_contig_306_pilon_pilon-processed-gene-0.1   gene1
> maker-tulip_contig_306_pilon_pilon-augustus-gene-0.12 gene2
> maker-tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon-augustus-gene-0.4   gene3
> ```

expected outcome:

> ```
> tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon   .   contig  1   93354   .   .   .   ID=tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon;Name=tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon
> tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon   maker   gene    19497   23038   .   +   .   ID=gene3;Name=gene3
> tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon   maker   mRNA    19497   23038   .   +   .   ID=gene3-mRNA-1;Parent=gene3;Name=gene3-mRNA-1;_AED=0.00;_eAED=0.00;_QI=418|1|1|1|0|0|3|2100|206
> ```

I have tried to use:

`while read -r pattern  replacement; do sed -i "s/$pattern/$replacement/" file.gff3 ; done < rename.txt`

But based on the answer below I am using AWK now instead. I use the script (**the exact same indentation as given by Ed Morton** but copying it here changes it slightly):

> ```
> NR==FNR {
>  map[$1] = $2
>  next 
> } 
> {
>  for (old in map) {
>     gsub(old,map[old])
>  }
>  print 
> }
> ```

To run I use:

```
awk -f tst.awk rename.txt original.gff3 > new.gff3
```

However, this script works with partial regexp matching, while it should be fully matching. How can I change this awk script so it becomes full matching?

The gff file is 7369803 lines long. The rename.txt file is 18477 lines long.

Any advice is welcome here!

Comment: What did you try? Post your efforts even if they failed

Comment: Ah yes forgot that! I tried to use a loop but the main problem is that sed should replace the gene name twice if it is given twice per line but it doesn't. I am using:
`while read -r pattern  replacement; do sed -i "s/$pattern/$replacement/" file.gff3 ; done < rename.txt`

Comment: The other issue is that this is extremely slow. I have >18000 gene names to replace and it takes forever..

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output for your posted sample input. Yes, that approach would take forever (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) and you should be using awk for this, not sed, so you might want to tag your question with awk.

Comment: You're looping 18,477 times once per line of the 7,369,803 lines file - that's 136,171,850,031 calls to `gsub()` so yeah, that'll take a while! Is there any way to identify lines in the .gff3 file that you don't need to perform replacements on or reduce how many replacements might be necessary on a given line? If not then the awk script you have now is the fastest way to do what you want.

Comment: The other thing to be aware of is that the sed script you posted, and so also the awk script I wrote, is doing partial regexp matching. What that means is that if you have 2 "patterns" in rename.txt that look like `augustus-gene-0.12` and `augustus-gene-0.1` then the `.`s in there will be treated as regexp metachars (since it's **regexp matching**) which mean "any character" and so `0.1` will match `051` or any other similar string, and `augustus-gene-0.1 -> gene1` will change `augustus-gene-0.12` to `gene12` **IF** it comes first in rename.txt (since it's **partial matching**).

Comment: IMHO the potential for incorrect replacement would far outweigh the speed of execution but idk, maybe something in your data makes that impossible. We can change the code to do full string matching or partial string matching or full regexp matching instead of partial regexp matching if any of that is undesirable.

Comment: Actually - one thing you might be able to do to speed things up is split your `.gff3` file into smaller files and run the awk script on each simultaneously using GNU parallel, then recombine them afterwards. I've never used it myself but you can google GNU parallel.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @EdMorton ! And thanks for the clear explanation. I was not aware that the awk script would work with partial regexp matching. It is quit important that the exact same replacement occurs (via full regexp matching) because otherwise genes etc. gets linked to the wrong contig! Speed is far less important than correctly replacing the strings, I can let it run for days if needed. But than, how can I change the script to let it become fully matching?

Comment: See my updated answer. It's far more robust than what we had before and should run literally about 5,000 times faster than the current approach if the rest of your .giff3 lines look like your example. To be clear - given what I know now about your problem, you should not do regexp matching (as all sed scripts do and I started off by replicating in the awk script), you should do string matching as you don't want any regexp metachars in either file to be treated as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does a full string match from after `=` to the end of `-gene=<number>` on each line of .gff3 and should be orders of magnitude faster and more robust than what we had been doing previously since it only replaces the 1-3 strings actually found in each line of the original.gff3 file rather than trying to replace all 18,000+ strings that exist in the rename.txt file:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    map[$1] = $2
    next
}
{
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,/((ID|Parent|Name)=)([^;]+-gene-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(.*)/,a) ) {
        old = a[3]
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) a[1] (old in map ? map[old] : old)
        tail = a[4]
    }
    print head tail
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk rename.txt original.gff3
tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon .   contig  1   93354   .   .   .   ID=tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon;Name=tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon
tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon maker   gene    19497   23038   .   +   .   ID=gene3;Name=gene3
tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon maker   mRNA    19497   23038   .   +   .   ID=gene3-mRNA-1;Parent=gene3;Name=gene3-mRNA-1;_AED=0.00;_eAED=0.00;_QI=418|1|1|1|0|0|3|2100|206
```

It uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() - I assume you have GNU awk available (or can install it) since you were using GNU sed.

So, the `match()` is isolating a string (that then gets stored in `old`) from the current line of `original.gff3` that **might** be in `rename.txt` (as stored in `map[]` in the first block) and then the `old in map` is testing if that string actually is in `rename.txt` or not and, if so, replacing `old` with the corresponding new value from `map[]`. That's all inside a `while` that loops as long as `match()` keeps finding new strings that are candidates to be replaced on the current line.

So instead of the original awk script below (and sed script in your question) that loops once for every one of the 18,000+ lines in `rename.txt`, the above only loops once for every string in the current line of `original.gff3` that might need to be replaced which, per your posted sample input, is only up to 3 times.

---

Original answer based on just speeding up your shell loop calling sed:

Something like this is what you need:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    map[$1] = $2
    next
}
{
    for (old in map) {
        gsub(old,map[old])
    }
    print
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk repl.txt foo.gff3
tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon .   contig  1   93354   .   .   .   ID=tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon;Name=tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon
tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon maker   gene    19497   23038   .   +   .   ID=gene3;Name=gene3
tulip_contig_65_pilon_pilon maker   mRNA    19497   23038   .   +   .   ID=gene3-mRNA-1;Parent=gene3;Name=gene3-mRNA-1;_AED=0.00;_eAED=0.00;_QI=418|1|1|1|0|0|3|2100|206
```

There are some decisions about string vs regexp matching and full vs partial matching that also applied to your shell+sed loop so think about your full requirements and provide sample input/output to test with and then we can massage this to suit if this doesn't do exactly what you want. Right now it's doing partial regexp matching just like the sed command in your question would do.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`, quite similar in logic as the `awk` answer

```
perl -ne 'if(!$#ARGV){ @n = split; $h{$n[0]}=$n[1] } else{ 
          s/(ID|Name|Parent)=\K[^;]+-gene-\d+\.\d+/exists $h{$&} ? $h{$&} : $&/ge;
          print }' rename.txt original.gff3
```

- `if(!$#ARGV)` to process only the first file
- `@n = split` to get key and value for renaming map

  - `$h{$n[0]}=$n[1]` the map
- `(ID|Name|Parent)=\K` to mark the starting location, won't be part of matching portion
- `[^;]+-gene-\d+\.\d+` **please** check if all your genes follow this format, it cannot have `;` character and always ends with `-` followed by `gene` followed by digits followed by `.` followed by digits, otherwise this will not work
- `exists $h{$&}` check if the matched portion exists as a key in the map and if so, use the value from the map else don't change the gene name

---

I did some speed test, but it may be differ substantially for your real use case. **Edit** - just realized that `t2` created below is useless as it will only have 3 different mappings.

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $_ x 1000000' original.gff3 > t1
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $_ x 10000' rename.txt > t2

$ time perl -ne 'if(!$#ARGV){ @n = split; $h{$n[0]}=$n[1] } else{ 
            s/(ID|Name|Parent)=\K[^;]+-gene-\d+\.\d+/exists $h{$&} ? $h{$&} : $&/ge;
            print }' t2 t1 > m1 
real    0m17.473s

$ time awk -f tst.awk t2 t1 > m2    
real    2m53.598s

$ # assuming your input is ASCII
$ time LC_ALL=C awk -f tst.awk t2 t1 > m3
real    1m53.976s

$ du -h t1 t2 m1
591M    t1
1.9M    t2
371M    m1

$ diff -sq m1 m2
Files m1 and m2 are identical
$ diff -sq m1 m3
Files m1 and m3 are identical
```

Answer (score 1):

Shell script attempts will tend to be O(n×m), which for 7369803×18477 is huge.

I'm not about to write the code, but for something this large, I'd write an ad hoc program in a language such as C or python:

- Add a line number to the beginning of each line of the data file.
- Sort the data file on the keyword field.
- Sort the rename file on the keyword field.
- Walk through the two sorted files in parallel (the "ad_hoc" program):

  - if the map key sorts before the data key, read the next map record.
  - else:

    - if the keys match, make the substitution.
    - write out the data record
    - read the next data record
- Sort the result by line number.
- Strip off the line numbers.

The computational complexity will be entirely from the sort operations, O(n×log(n)), which will be incredibly faster than anything with nested loops.  The ad_hoc program itself is linear, O(n+m), simply reading the two files and processing each line once, without any loops.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Assumes "%" does not occur in either file

ad_hoc \
<( sed <map  -e 's/\([^ ]*\)  *\([^ ]*\)$/\1%\2/' \
 | sort -t '%' -k 1,1 ) \
<( sed  <input  '/./=' \
 | sed '/./N; s/\n/ /' \
 | sed -e 's/ID=\([^;]*\);/ID=%\1%;/' \
 | sort -t '%' -k 2,2 ) \
| sort -t ' ' -k 1,1n \
| sed -e 's/^[0-9]* *//'
```

All you need is the "ad_hoc" program.